# Accessing locally created subprogram inside package in Ada

Tags: ada, ada95

Can anyone please let me know, how to get access to locally created subprogram inside package in order to test the locally created subprogram independently using GNATest (Aunit), instead of integrating locally created subprogram in called function/procedure.

Comment: Instead of repeating the question, please [edit] your question to include a [mre] that illustrates the use case you describe.

Answer (score 1):

If the subprogram you want to test is declared in the private part of the spec, you could create a special test-only child package to give access to it (or maybe to contain the tests?)

Comment: gnattest already generates  the test skeletons in child-packages